# Improve performance of wide GroupBy + write

Tags: performance, pyspark, azure-databricks

I need to tune a job that looks like below.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

dimensions  = ["d1", "d2", "d3"] 
measures    = ["m1", "m2", "m3"]
expressions = [F.sum(m).alias(m) for m in measures]

# Aggregation
aggregate = (spark.table("input_table")
                  .groupBy(*dimensions)
                  .agg(*expressions))

# Write out summary table 
aggregate.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("output_table")
```

The input table contains transactions, partitioned by date, 8 files per date.
It has 108 columns and roughly half a billion records. The aggregated result has 37 columns and ~20 million records.

I am unable to make any sort of improvement in the runtime whatever I do, so I would like to understand **what are the things that affect the performance of this aggregation**, i.e. what are the things I can potentially change?

The only thing that seems to help is to manually partition the work, i.e. starting multiple concurrent copies of the same code but with different date ranges.

Answer (score 0):

to the best of my understanding currently the groupBy clause doesn't include the 'date' column so you are actually aggregating all dates in the query and you are not using the input table partition at all.
you can add the "date" column to the partitionBy clause and then you will sum up the measures for each date.

also, as for the `input_table`, when it is built, if possible, you can additionally partition it by `d1`, `d2`, `d3` if they don't have a high cardinality or at least some of them.

finally the `input_table` will benefit from a columnar file type (parquet) so you won't have to i/o all 108 columns if you are using something like csv. assuming you are using something like parquet but just in case.

Comment: Good points! I'm actually filtering on a specific range of dates to produce monthly summaries so partition pruning takes place. Would including the date column in the groupBY() cause the aggregation to take place on different nodes/cores? It sounds like that would reduce the amount of shuffling.
Both input and output table are parquet tables.

Comment: >Would including the date column in the groupBY() cause the aggregation to take place on different nodes/cores?   
No, but you would shuffle less data. you don't require the groupBy sum across all 30 days but for each day a different result. from what I understand this isn't your business need.   

You can run a daily job that sums every date-1 and puts the daily aggregated results in an aggregate_stg delta table with "append" write move, partitioned by date.
then when running a "monthly summary" you can filter the range of dates from the aggregate_stg table and just get what you need.

Comment: I tricked you into answering the simplified question, but in the real case the output data has to be re-computed. I don't understand where the time is being spent, that's why I'm asking a simpler question.